SQL query to check if a particular table is available under a database and apply filters
I am trying to check if a particular table name is available under a schema or not using the below query
SELECT name as Database_name,
CASE WHEN HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1 and
(CASE WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' THEN OBJECT_ID( QUOTENAME( name ) + '.[dbo].[Item]','U' )
END IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as Active_Flag
FROM sys.databases where name like 'Aug_%';

Now in addition to the above condition i have to also check the table **item ** has business_date column greater than 2018 onwards and get only those database names. Tried different options, any help or guidance here?
Eg:



DB Name
Table_name
business_date




Aug_01
Item
01-01-2015


Aug_02
Item
12-31-2018


Aug_05
Item
06-10-2013



Expected Result
Aug_02

You will have to use dynamic SQL for this, as you'll need to dynamically query the table. In truth the problem appears to be your design; why do you have a different database for (what appears to be) each day/year (unlear if 01 means "01 August", "August 1901" or "August 2001").

Same table name is present under different DB's. all i have to do is read the table "Item" from the DB which hold data after Jan 1st 2018 and ignore the rest.

That doesn't change my point. Your comment just repeats what we already know; your design is the issue and you need to use dynamic SQL.


Write your statement without dynamic sql, select * from Aug_05.dbo.Item where business_date >= '...' 2) Then create a dynamic sql string that fetches whatever dynamic data you're needed 3) Finally, debug and execute it until you're satisfied


@ThomA In theory you could use an IF and deferred object resolution should take care of it https://dbfiddle.uk/dpuX4_Gj

I admit, I'm assuming that the OP will have a Jun_24 database next month, @Charlieface .
